# Improve performance of Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j, shortest-path

I'm using NEO4j enterprise edition, and I have created a database with around 20200 relations and some 15000 nodes. When I try to find the 3-shortest path between two random nodes, it takes around 3-15 seconds(which is quite slow). How can I improve the response time from neo4j?

I'm using Ubuntu 16X and I have 4 GB ram configured.

Comment: You have to provide more detail. What does your graph look like and your code/queries, is this localhost or remote connection etc

Comment: it is on localhost, relationship is like 
    C0000039,C0001555,test
    C0000039,C0001688,test
    C0000039,C0002776,test .....

and nodes are like 
   C0243192
   C1522005
   C1524024
   C1524059
   C1623416
   C1959616.

I created database using batch import tool
    neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes:concept "MRREl-nodes,nheader" --relationships:test "MRREl-relations,rheader" --deliminiter ,  --skip-duplicate-node true